# Why didn't future Nebula receive the same kind of sync up/feedback to alert her to past Nebula's awareness?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, the way that Thanos was made aware of the Avengers' plans was because the Nebula from the past who was serving him somehow "synced up" with the future version of herself who was working with the Avengers. As such, she could "see" the future Nebula's thoughts and memories which were recorded in her cyber brain. But, plot convenience aside..

**Why was this connection only working one way?**

Thanos was only made aware of it because there was some sudden "feedback" that occurred when both Nebula's were in the same time at once. This is what allowed past Nebula to see all future Nebula's in the moment memories, and gave them details to the plans. But why couldn't future Nebula then "feel" when they were tapping into her memories the same way?

Answer (score 7):

She did, just not at the same time as Bad Nebula did. Bad Nebula noticed the sync up earlier than Nebula, perhaps because she is running an older version of herself Or because Nebula is connecting into Bad Nebula’s memory bank. Both have the same reaction when they notice the sync up, freezing, jolts with the memories leaking through.

> SUDDENLY, BAD NEBULA STAGGERS, hand to the wall.
>
> [...]
>
> SUDDENLY, A HOLO-PROJECTION OF RHODEY BEAMS FROM HER EYE. Thanos watches, curious, as NEBULA DROPS TO A KNEE.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame*</sub>

> RHODEY TAPS HIS CUFF, SHRINKING AWAY. Nebula goes for hers...BUT HER EYES ROLL BACK.
>
> SHE COLLAPSES, SEIZING VIOLENTLY, THEN GOING STILL. Her eyes snap open, projecting a hologram of...THANOS.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame*</sub>

Comment: Excellent answer as always, my +1. Btw, congrats on reaching 100K!

Comment: Also, nine years of future data arriving is easier to notice than (initially) small changes to nine-year-old records.